# Python Telethon - Send messages at timed intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm trying to send a message to my group at defined time intervals, but I get a warning in the output the first time I try to send the message. Next times no warning, but nothing is posted in the group. I'm the owner of the group so in theory there shouldn't be any permissions issues.

**Code**

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
import schedule

def sendImage():
    apiId = 1111111
    apiHash = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    phone = "+111111111111"
    client = TelegramClient(phone, apiId, apiHash)

    toChat = 1641242898

    client.start()

    print("Sending...")
    client.send_file(toChat, "./image.jpg", caption="Write text here")

    client.disconnect()
    return

def main():
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(sendImage)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output**

```
Sending...
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UploadMethods.send_file' was never awaited
  client.send_file(toChat, "./image.jpg", caption="Write text here")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Sending...
Sending...
Sending...
```

Comment: You can use `scheduler` instead of `schedule`. We designed `scheduler` for easy asyncio and timezone support. Here is an example how to use `scheduler` with asyncio: https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/examples/asyncio.html

Answer (score 0):

Telethon uses `asyncio`, but `schedule` wasn't designed with `asyncio` in mind. You should consider using an `asyncio`-based alternative to `schedule`, or just use Python's builtin functions in the `asyncio` module to "schedule" things:

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient

def send_image():
    ...
    client = TelegramClient(phone, apiId, apiHash)

    await client.start()
    await client.send_file(toChat, "./image.jpg", caption="Write text here")
    await client.disconnect()

async def main():
    while True:  # forever
        await send_image()  # send image, then
        await asyncio.sleep(10)  # sleep 10 seconds

    # this is essentially "every 10 seconds call send_image"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

You should also consider creating and `start()`ing the client inside `main` to avoid recreating it every time.

Comment: Can I send file like this to a user, too?

Comment: Yes, `send_file` can receive an user as the first parameter to send it in the private conversation with them.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you do not give time for the operation to be done, try these changes :

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import schedule

async def sendImage(): # <- make it async
    apiId = 1111111
    apiHash = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    phone = "+111111111111"
    client = TelegramClient(phone, apiId, apiHash)

    toChat = 1641242898

    client.start()

    print("Sending...")
    await client.send_file(toChat, "./image.jpg", caption="Write text here") # <- here too add await

    client.disconnect()
    return

def main():
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(client.loop.run_until_complete(sendImage))

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

other thing i don't think that you should keep connecting and disconnecting, in my opinion client.start() should be out of this function and client.disconnect too

Answer (score -1):

As the output says you need to await the response of the coroutine. The code may trigger exceptions which should be handled.

```
try:
    client = TelegramClient(...)
    client.start()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception while starting the client - {e}")
else:
    try:
        ret_value = await client.send_file(...)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception while sending the message - {e}")
    else:
        print(f"Message sent. Return Value {ret_value}")
```